JNI CallStaticObjectMethod is causing crash with Java 21
The company I work for recently moved to Java 21 from Java 8, which updated the JNI version as well that is used with interoperatibility with C++. All the function (written in C++) called through JNI work fine on Java 8, but
the function CallStaticObjectMethod is throwing Access Violation exception and causing crash.
This function is used to call a static method on Java side.
The function which invokes CallStaticObjectMethod is as below:
jobject Bindings::ToSystemArchObj(JNIEnv* env, const std::string& arch)
{
    if (env == nullptr || arch == ARCH_UNSUPPORTED)
    {
        return nullptr;
    }
    jobject jstr = env->NewStringUTF(arch.c_str()); // I have tried converting the type of jstr from jobject to jstring

    processArchObj = env->CallStaticObjectMethod(JniProcessInfoDTO::SystemArchClass, JniProcessInfoDTO::ofMethodId, jstr); // THIS LINE IS THROWING access violation and causing crash


    return processArchObj;
}

The JniProcessInfoDTO::SystemArchClass and JniProcessInfoDTO::ofMethodId argument for this function are being initialized in a separate function which is below:
void JniProcessInfoDTO::initClass(JNIEnv* env)
{
    jclass const localProcessInfoDTO = env->FindClass(JavaTypes::ProcessInfoDTO.c_str());
    ProcessInfoDTORef = reinterpret_cast<jclass>(env->NewGlobalRef(localProcessInfoDTO));
    initFieldIDs(env);
    // std::string const SystemArch = "Lcom/company/mfw/model/dto/SystemArch;";
    SystemArchClass = env->FindClass(JavaTypes::SystemArch.c_str());
    
    // (Ljava/lang/String;)Lcom/company/mfw/model/dto/SystemArch;
    const std::string ofSign = "(" + JavaTypes::String + ")" + JavaTypes::SystemArch; //// std::string const String = "java/lang/String;";

    ofMethodId = env->GetStaticMethodID(SystemArchClass, "of", ofSign.c_str());
}

The Java side static function do which is supposed to get called looks like below:
package com.company.mfw.model.dto;

public enum SystemArch {

    X86, X86_64, UNSUPPORTED;

    public static SystemArch of(String arch) {
        try {
            return SystemArch.valueOf(arch);
        } catch (Exception ignored) {
            return UNSUPPORTED;
        }
    }

}

The JNI is being loaded and unloaded in the following way:
extern "C"
{
    // cppcheck-suppress unusedFunction
    JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM* vm, void*)
    {
        // This is an entry point for initialization of Java classes.
        // All required Java classes must exist and must be initialized here.
        // JNI_OnLoad must not be wrapped with Safe Environment.
        // JVM should be crashed in case of exceptions here.
        

        JniGlobals::JVMConnector::InitJavaVM(vm);

        JavaVMAttachArgs args;
        args.version = JNI_VERSION_21;
        args.name = nullptr;
        args.group = nullptr;
        JNIEnv* env = nullptr;

        vm->AttachCurrentThread((void**)&env, &args);
        JniContext::Current().JniEnv = env;
        JniGlobals::unmaskFPSR();

        GdiplusStartup(&JniGlobals::gdiplusToken, &JniGlobals::gdiplusStartupInput, nullptr);

        Bindings::JniComponentDTO::initClass(env);
        Bindings::JniWindowDTO::initClass(env);
        Bindings::JniPointDTO::initClass(env);
        Bindings::JniDimensionDTO::initClass(env);
        Bindings::JniRectangleDTO::initClass(env);
        Bindings::JniProcessInfoDTO::initClass(env); 
        Bindings::JniProcessStartupInfoDTO::initClass(env);
        Bindings::JniProcessEndInfoDTO::initClass(env);
        Bindings::JniKeyDTO::initClass(env);
        Bindings::JniNativeMouseEvent::initClass(env);
        Bindings::JniNativeKeyEvent::initClass(env);
        Bindings::JniHooksSettings::initClass(env);
        Bindings::WinSessionDTO::initClass(env);

        JniGlobals::TimeManager::GetInstance().InitJavaHandlers(env);

        JniGlobals::JavaObjectFactory::JavaObjectFactoryClass = env->FindClass("com/company/mfw/bridge/internal/JavaObjectsFactory");
        JniGlobals::JavaObjectFactory::NewStringMethodID
            = env->GetStaticMethodID(JniGlobals::JavaObjectFactory::JavaObjectFactoryClass, "newString", "([B)Ljava/lang/String;");

        Log::GetInstance().Init();

        LOG_TRACE(L"BEGIN");
        auto osInfo = JniGlobals::WindowsSystemInfo::GetInstance().ReadOsInfo();
        std::string csd(osInfo.szCSDVersion);
        LOG_INFO(L"System info. Version: {}.{}, Build: {}, Platform ID: {}, CSD Version: {}", (int)osInfo.dwMajorVersion,
                 (int)osInfo.dwMinorVersion, (int)osInfo.dwBuildNumber, (int)osInfo.dwPlatformId,
                 csd.length() > 0 ? StringsConverter::StringToWstring(csd) : L"<empty>");

        return JNI_VERSION_21;
    }

    // cppcheck-suppress unusedFunction
    JNIEXPORT void JNICALL JNI_OnUnload(JavaVM*, void*)
    {
        LOG_TRACE(L"BEGIN");

        Gdiplus::GdiplusShutdown(JniGlobals::gdiplusToken);

        JNIEnv* env = JniContext::Current().JniEnv;
        Bindings::JniComponentDTO::releaseClass(env);
        Bindings::JniWindowDTO::releaseClass(env);
        Bindings::JniPointDTO::releaseClass(env);
        Bindings::JniDimensionDTO::releaseClass(env);
        Bindings::JniRectangleDTO::releaseClass(env);
        Bindings::JniProcessInfoDTO::releaseClass(env);
        Bindings::JniProcessStartupInfoDTO::releaseClass(env);
        Bindings::JniProcessEndInfoDTO::releaseClass(env);
        Bindings::JniKeyDTO::releaseClass(env);
        Bindings::JniNativeMouseEvent::releaseClass(env);
        Bindings::JniNativeKeyEvent::releaseClass(env);
        Bindings::JniHooksSettings::releaseClass(env);
        Bindings::WinSessionDTO::releaseClass(env);
    }

} // extern "C"

The JNI documentation does not contain any information about this function. Can anyone help me here?
UPDATE 1: All the other JNI methods work fine only this one is causing crash
UPDATE 2 All these functions are called to convert a C++ object type to Java type. The Bindings::ToSystemArchObj method is being called by the method which is doing this type conversion here:
/**
 * Converts a ProcessInfoPtr to a Java ProcessInfoDTO object.
 *
 * @param env The JNI environment pointer.
 * @param pi The ProcessInfoPtr object.
 * @return The corresponding Java ProcessInfoDTO object or nullptr if the environment or ProcessInfoPtr is null.
 */
jobject Bindings::ToJavaType(JNIEnv* env, ProcessInfoPtr pi)
{
    if (env == nullptr || pi == nullptr)
    {
        return nullptr;  // Return nullptr if environment or ProcessInfoPtr is null
    }

    jobject joProcessInfoDTO = env->AllocObject(JniProcessInfoDTO::ProcessInfoDTORef);  // Allocate a new ProcessInfoDTO object

    env->SetIntField(joProcessInfoDTO, JniProcessInfoDTO::processPidFieldId, pi->pid);  // Set process PID field
    env->SetIntField(joProcessInfoDTO, JniProcessInfoDTO::processParentPidFieldId, pi->parentPid);  // Set process parent PID field

    env->SetObjectField(joProcessInfoDTO, JniProcessInfoDTO::processChildProcessFieldId, ToJavaType(env, pi->childProcesses));  // Set child processes field

    env->SetObjectField(joProcessInfoDTO, JniProcessInfoDTO::processCommandLineFieldId, ToJavaType(env, pi->commandLine));  // Set command line field
    env->SetObjectField(joProcessInfoDTO, JniProcessInfoDTO::processNameFieldId, ToJavaType(env, pi->name));  // Set process name field
    env->SetObjectField(joProcessInfoDTO, JniProcessInfoDTO::processOwnerFieldId, ToJavaType(env, pi->owner));  // Set process owner field

    env->SetIntField(joProcessInfoDTO, JniProcessInfoDTO::processResidentBytesFieldId, pi->residentBytes);  // Set resident bytes field
    env->SetIntField(joProcessInfoDTO, JniProcessInfoDTO::processTotalBytesFieldId, pi->totalBytes);  // Set total bytes field
    env->SetIntField(joProcessInfoDTO, JniProcessInfoDTO::processSystemMillsFieldId, pi->systemMillis);  // Set system milliseconds field
    env->SetIntField(joProcessInfoDTO, JniProcessInfoDTO::processUserMillsFieldId, pi->userMillis);  // Set user milliseconds field

    env->SetObjectField(joProcessInfoDTO, JniProcessInfoDTO::processArchFieldId, ToSystemArchObj(env, pi->arch));  // Set process architecture field

    return joProcessInfoDTO;  // Return the ProcessInfoDTO object
}

The above function is trying to convert ProcessInfo to a Java ProcessInfoDTO object. ProcessInfo type is as below.
class ProcessInfo
{
public:
    ProcessInfo()
        : pid(-1), parentPid(0), commandLine(L""), name(L""), owner(L""), residentBytes(0), totalBytes(0), systemMillis(0), userMillis(0),
          arch("")
    {
        childProcesses.resize(0);
    };

    ~ProcessInfo() = default;

public:
    int pid;
    int parentPid;
    std::vector<int> childProcesses;
    std::wstring commandLine;
    std::wstring name;
    std::wstring owner;

    long residentBytes;
    long totalBytes;
    long systemMillis;
    long userMillis;

    std::string arch;
};

and part of ProcessInfoDTO type is as below:
public class ProcessInfoDTO {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -212324578578245L;

    private int pid;
    private int parentPid;
    private String commandLine;
    private String name;
    private String owner;
    private int[] childProcesses;

    private long residentBytes;
    private long totalBytes;
    private long systemMillis;
    private long userMillis;

    private SystemArch arch;

    public int getPid() {
        return pid;
    }

    public void setPid(int pid) {
        this.pid = pid;
    }
    // Some more function definitions
    // Some more function definitions
}


Which distribution and exact version of JDK 21?

@aled - We are using azul version from https://shorturl.at/XOd6O and version
openjdk version "21.0.4" 2024-07-16 LTS OpenJDK Runtime Environment Zulu21.36+17-CA (build 21.0.4+7-LTS) OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Zulu21.36+17-CA (build 21.0.4+7-LTS, mixed mode, sharing)

Have you tried a different version and provider?

No. But good point let me try that, which do you recommend. Oracle?

SystemArch = "Lcom/company/mfw/model/dto/SystemArch;"; <-- I don't know if that's just a typo in your comment, but there shouldn't be any leading L and closing ; around the class names that you pass to FindClass.

What does arch contain when the crash occurs? Have you verified that the NewStringUTF call is successful? (i.e. that jstr is non-null and that env->ExceptionCheck() returns JNI_FALSE). By the way, who is calling ToSystemArchObj? (e.g. who takes care of deleting the jstr local reference).

@StewieGGriffin Try an OpenJDK distribution like Temurin. I would recommend trying also with a previous version like OpenJDK 17. Also [edit] your question to add debugging details. As others have commented we don't have them or how to reproduce. A [mre] would be ideal.

Also add the -Xcheck:jni flag to be extra strict re JNI code. Edit your question with all the constants you put under JavaTypes since you may be mixing up java canonical class names and class names in signatures.

I see absolutely no error checking, nor any checks for pending exceptions.  So you never know when something does fail, and you keep running blindly after any failure.  And that is a recipe for causing the JVM to crash.

UPDATE 1: All the other JNI methods work fine only this one is causing crash  That is WRONG.  You can not say that, BECAUSE YOU ARE NOT CHECKING RETURN VALUES FOR ERRORS NOR FOR ANY PENDING EXCEPTIONS.  Significant restrictions to both JNI and reflection have been added to Java post Java 8.  FIX YOUR CODE TO CHECK ALL CALLS FOR FAILURE AND EXCEPTIONS.  Like you should have been doing from the beginning.

@AndrewHenle - Maybe I already did that and found no help after doing that?

@StewieGGriffin Sure you did.  You checked every return value from a JNI call for success and you also checked for pending exceptions after every call.  And you only thought to mention that after I called you out for not doing it not once but twice?  JNI calls don't just randomly SEGV.  Somewhere your code is laying a land mine, and if you're not checking every call for both failure and pending exceptions, you'll continue to flail away on your Easter Egg hunt

You can either implement a methodical approach and actually check every call for bad return values and pending exceptions, or you can keep wondering what's going wrong.  You get to pick.

The issue was because of the use of C style vararg function.
    jvalue args[1];
    args[0].l = jstr;

    jobject processArchObj = env->CallStaticObjectMethodA(JniProcessInfoDTO::SystemArchClass, JniProcessInfoDTO::ofMethodId, args);

